# iOS - Why isn't there a dropdown menu implemented

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu

I've read a thread on here, saying "You are going against a lot of what is defined in Apples Human Interface Guidelines" at someone trying to implement a dropdown menu.

I'm curious, why isn't there any dropdown menu implemented, or why is it against Apple HIG?

PS: It's fairly easy to implement, create a button, when touchUpInside, present a tableView, and then at tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: just change the text on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it's because the Picker is a friendlier (and prettier) control for a touch interface. There is no "absolute science" because they're guidelines, but the most important thing, from a UX perspective, is that the platform is consistent and - if nothing else - that's a convention that you're breaking when you implement a traditional dropdown control.

Why not refer directly to the HIG for this sort of thing?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW23

Comment: I don't know why they like pickers, it REALLY looks obnoxious, especially considering you can't change the height (just by hiding in with a view)...

Oh then again, I could just do it the way I wanted (creating a button then presenting a picker  then hiding it when picked).

Comment: Your opinion on pickers as a developer is fairly irrelevant - it is a convention of the platform that you should be conforming to if you want your users to get the UI experience they are expecting. If you want your app to look like a cheap port from another platform, go ahead and override the convention.

Comment: It doesn't have to look like cheap port from another platform. It may look even better! It's not difficult to make custom control for drop-down which looks and behave better than this crappy picker from Apple.